# Does Bard's Jack of all Trades increase passive checks?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, bard, proficiency

Jack of all Trades increases all ability checks in which the bard is not proficient.
Passive checks are ability checks. (PHB5e p.54 & 175, respectively)

Does that mean I can add half my proficiency to Passive Perception (Wisdom)?

I know it works on initiative, so probably on passive checks as well, right?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Yup, you halve-and-add your proficiency bonus to even passive checks.

> **Jack of all Trades.** ...add half your proficiency bonus, rounded down, to *any ability check* you make that doesn't already include your proficiency bonus. (PHB p.54, emphasis mine)

Combined with

> **Passive Checks.** A passive check *is a special kind of ability check*....
>
> Here's how to determine a character's total for a passive check:
>
> > 10 + all modifiers that normally apply to the check.
>
> (PHB p.175, emphasis mine)

So as long your *Jack of All Trades* modifier normally applies to your Perception (Wisdom) check, then it applies to the passive version.